# Any other alternative for gridster to use in IE6+?

Tags: javascript, gridster

i have an application which uses gridster library but whenever i use this in IE6-7 browser its not working at all.Please suggest me some plugin for same work .

Answer (score 0):

I've used this one a lot. It has many options: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Wiki: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php

Main Page: http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/?mobile=0

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: thanks @gfrobenius .but which links is more suitable i didn't get  how to use it .

Comment: They are all helpful. Start with the first link, look at the examples, they give front end code that goes with it. Been a long time since I used it but I remember the PHP back end code I wrote cause I just stuck with the free version. I still have code and could help on it but that's a different question.

Comment: Actually I just looked. The examples show the backend PHP code now. I think it was the complex searching functions I had to code myself.  They have a version you can buy and they give you all the PHP libraries that do everything you need. I never needed it, I just hit F12, watch what the grid sends, figured it out myself. The wiki is very helpful also.